Teams Message Extension: add Authorization Header to URL accessing costum web server
I wonder wether it is somehow possible to add an authorization header to the call which is triggered by my message extension to my custom web service.
I couldn't find anything in MessagingExtensionActionResponse, TaskModuleContinueResponse or TaskModuleTaskInfo...
Thanks for your help,
Anne
Example from MS for a message extension calling a URL on a custom web service:
protected override Task<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                    return new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
                    {
                        Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
                        {
                            Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo
                            {
                                Height = 200,
                                Width = 400,
                                Title = "Task Module HTML Page",
                                Url = "https://myserver.com/htmlpage.html",
                            },
                        },
                    };


Unfortunately, the standard MessagingExtensionActionResponse, TaskModuleContinueResponse, and TaskModuleTaskInfo do not directly support adding custom headers like authorization headers.

Thanks for your answer. Is there any other possibility which I can use to achieve this or does the call from teams to the web service have to be unauthorized?

One way is to handle the authorization within your custom web service. Here’s a general idea of how you can do it:

Ensure that your web service can handle authorization tokens. You can
pass the token as a query parameter or in the body of the request.

When your message extension triggers the call, include the
authorization token in the request. This can be done by modifying the
payload sent to your web service.


Here’s a simplified example of how you might modify the payload to include an authorization token:
const payload = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        // Your existing payload data
    })
};

fetch('https://your-custom-web-service-url', payload)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Handle the response data
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });

In this example, replace 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN' with the actual token you need to use for authorization.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. For the message extension I can only pass a url with the classes described and no post request.
